# Using Delphi 'with' keyword in brackets

Tags: delphi

I need to add some initialization without adding a variable declaration to the `var` section, so I try to do that by doing this:

```
sql.columns.Add(with TColumn.Create do
begin
   ColName := 'Price';
    As_  := 'MaxPrice';
end);
```

but Delphi raises an error while compiling.

Any ideas?

Comment: Collections usually return added object. Hard to say what is this, but for usually implemented collection you could write `with Sql.Columns.Add do begin ColName := 'Price'; As_  := 'MaxPrice'; end;`.

Comment: i work generally with dotnet-c#, other part Colmuns is TList<Columns>

Comment: What is the error? My guess would be that 'Add' expects a parameter but 'with' doesn't return a value. Note that even if your program compiled it would leak memory.

Comment: If you want help on an error message, you should post the exact text of the error message. Just paste it into your question (you can edit the question). But `with` is a construct, a statement. It is not a function and it can't be used as a parameter. It doesn't matter if this works, somehow, in C#. C# is not Delphi.

Comment: Of course it's a compiler error. It's invalid syntax.

Answer (score 5):

`TList<T>.Add()` expects a fully constructed object as input. The `with` keyword does not provide you access to the object it is operating on. You need to use a variable, whether you like it or not:

```
var
  col: TColumn;

col := TColumn.Create;
col.ColName := 'Price';
col.As_ := 'MaxPrice';
sql.columns.Add(col);
```

The alternative is to write a function instead, and use its special `Result`variable:

```
function MakeColumn(const AName, AAs: string): TColumn;
begin
  Result := TColumn.Create;
  Result.ColName := AName;
  Result.As_ := AAs;
end;

sql.columns.Add(MakeColumn('Price', 'MaxPrice'));
```